# Handling multiple forms in a single page [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested-loops, angular-ngmodel

So I have this page where a user should be able to log details for multiple projects he had applied to . Each project has multiple milestones and each milestone has a form where the user is able  to log in the details . I designed the page and all but the problem is when the user updates one form , it reflects on all the forms present in the page.
 This is my html where i display the form to the user.

```
<form>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Task Name</th>
            <th>Hours</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <p> {{project.id}}--{{milestone.id}} </p>
    <tbody ng-repeat="taskDetail in ::taskDetails">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:25px;">
                <input type="text" ng-model="taskDetail.date" required/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="taskDetail.taskname" required/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="taskDetail.hours" required/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" ng-model="taskDetail.milestone_id" value="{{ ::milestone.id }}" required/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeLast()">Remove</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <button ng-click="addRow()">Add Row</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button ng-click="savetask()"> Save </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the corresponding action is done in the controller by

```
 $scope.taskDetails = [{
        'date': '',
        'taskname': '',
        'hours': '',
        'milestone_id': ''
    }];

    $scope.addRow = function (taskDetail) {
        $scope.taskDetails.push({
            'date': "",
            'taskname': "",
            'hours': "",
            'milestone_id': ""
        });
    };

    $scope.removeLast = function () {
        var lastItem = $scope.taskDetails.length - 1;
        $scope.taskDetails.splice(lastItem);
    };

    $scope.savetask = function (id) {
        console.log("Details= " + id);
             myFrm = document.getElementById(frmId);
            $http.put('/api/v1/projects/'+ :project_id '/milestones/' +:milestone_id'  /timetracker', { timetracker: $scope.taskDetails
        })
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log($scope.taskDetails)
          flash.setMessage('Successfully logged your time', true);
        }, function(data) {
          flash.setMessage('Error updating bank account', false);
        })
    };
});
```

Milestone ID is unique for each form.

Comment: If I understand your question you want to store log details and preserve state in every pages,, then use an angular service to hold your data, its a singleton and can be shared across views and controllers.

Comment: Its not in multiple pages but all the forms are in a single page with each form belonging to a single milestone and there are multiple milestones for each project